# How to capture mouse click event of tab if page having sevral controls

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have vb.net application.

I have a form which contains tab control and have several tab pages.

In below image we can see the second tab have been selected.

I want to capture mouse click event if I click anywhere when tab page 2 is selected.

Note : I have several controls on tab page 2.

How to do that ?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to intercept a mouse click?  What if one of the controls is a button?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `I want to capture mouse click event if I click anywhere when tab page 2 is selected.`, does this mean just inside of `TabPage2`, anywhere on your form or anywhere including outside of your application?